Does Microsoft Graph API support 'createddatetime' property for contacts?
On Microsoft website, it clearly says that createdDateTime property is supported for contacts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/contact?view=graph-rest-1.0.
However, when I try to run https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contacts?$select=createdDateTime on the graph explorer, I get:

{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#contacts(createdDateTime)",
"@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contacts?$select=createdDateTime&$skiptoken=RFNwdAIAAQAAACxDb250YWN0XzEzODFiZTQ5LTk4ZGYtNGI5MS1hODdkLWUzMjgzYjdkZTI1ZSxDb250YWN0XzEzODFiZTQ5LTk4ZGYtNGI5MS1hODdkLWUzMjgzYjdkZTI1ZQAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
"value": [
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{}
]
}

So is it not supported after all?

The query that you are currently using is to fetch list of organizational contacts which won't have createdDateTime property in response like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contacts

Response:

When I ran same query as you in Graph Explorer selecting createdDateTime, I too got blank response like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contacts?$select=createdDateTime

Response:


Note that, organizational contacts are different from contacts created under users.

The MS document that you are referring where createdDateTime property is supported for contacts is applied to the contacts created under users.
When I tried to query the same for contacts created under user, it returned createdDateTime property in response like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$select=createdDateTime

Response:

